# Riverpod `StreamProvider` stream causes Flutter `TextFormField` to loose cursor entirely on 1st character input despite no stream events emitted

Tags: flutter, riverpod, flutter-riverpod, flutter-hooks

### Overview

The issue consists of the Flutter `TextFormField` loosing its cursor entirely upon the first character being inputted via a keyboard - see full replication steps below.

Note the `TextFormField` is watching a stream, which should not (& does not) emit any events during **Issue Replication Steps 2-3 below**. Upon `onChanged` within the `TextFormField`, the `currentValueProvider` Riverpod `StateProvider` is updated with the `TextFormField` value.

The **minimum working example** below features a `valueStreamProvider` Riverpod `StreamProvider` which may appear a bit of an odd use case - this is due to the actual `valueStreamProvider` Riverpod `StreamProvider` version being far more complex, however the below **minimum working example** demonstrates the issue that we are aiming to overcome.

Big shout out to Riverpod, fantastic bit of kit, thank you so much Remi Rousselet.

Please see full details of the issue below and we thank all feedback gratefully in advance. If you require any further details of examples please do not hesitate to reach out.

### Issue replication steps:

1. `flutter run` to open the web app. The `TextFormField` will then initialise with the text 'Test Value' as expected; the initial text/value of the `TextFormField` is populated via the `valueStreamProvider` Riverpod `StreamProvider` being watched.
2. Click in the `TextFormField` (cursor appears flashing as expected) & enter 1 x character (via a keyboard) - the issue then occurs where the cursor automatically disappears from the `TextFormField` and thus the user is no longer to type any further characters in the `TextFormField` (via a keyboard).
3. For a second time, click in the `TextFormField` (cursor appears flashing as expected)  & enter 1+ character(s) (via a keyboard) - the cursor in the `TextFormField` does not disappear (as expected) and the user is able to continue to type characters in the `TextFormField` (via a keyboard) as expected.

### Expected behaviour (which is not happening):

1. `flutter run` to open the web app. The `TextFormField` will then initialise with the text 'Test Value' as expected; the initial text/value of the `TextFormField` is populated via the `valueStreamProvider` Riverpod `StreamProvider` being watched.
2. Click in the `TextFormField` (cursor appears flashing as expected) & enter 1+ characters (as many characters as desired and via a keyboard). The cursor does not disappear from the 'TextFormField' at any point (unless a click event occurs which hits outside of the 'TextFormField').

Essentially as soon as the `currentValueProvider` Riverpod `StateProvider` is populated with 1+ character we wish the `TextFormField` to ignore (not receive) events from the `valueStreamProvider` Riverpod `StreamProvider` (thus the `currentValueProvider` Riverpod `StateProvider` is updated by the `TextFormField` to achieve this).

### From debugging, we have found:

- The `final TextEditingController controller = useTextEditingController();` correctly persists the state of the cursor position (throughout all of the Issue Replication Steps above). The `FocusNode` state is also persisted throughout all of the Issue Replication Steps above - and this focus is not lost throughout any of the steps.
- If we omit the `valueStreamProvider` Riverpod `StreamProvider` from the `TextFormField`, the issue in step 1 (Issue Replication Steps above) does not occur, so this is highly likely to be caused by the `valueStreamProvider` Riverpod `StreamProvider`. We have logged throughout the `valueStreamProvider` and no stream event is being emitted - perhaps the `StreamProvider` is emitting a loading event? Or?
- When the cursor is lost in **Step 1** from **Issue Replication Steps** above, logging has confirmed that the `TextformField` was rebuilt - thus probably the cause for the cursor being lost.

### Minimum working example:

Please create a new flutter web app and then paste in the below files:

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const ProviderScope(child: MyApp() ));
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData( primarySwatch: Colors.blue ),
      home: const Material(child: TextWidget()),
    );
  }
}

/// Riverpod Provider - current value
final currentValueProvider = StateProvider<String?>((final ref) => null);

/// Riverpod Provider - Value Stream
final valueStreamProvider = StreamProvider.autoDispose<String?>((final ref) async* {

  // DB Document StreamProvider watched here - *** not in use in this minimal 
  // example *** but to illustrate why a StreamProvider is required 
  // for valueStreamProvider
  // final String? firebaseDocumentStream = await ref.watch(firebaseDocumentStreamProvider
  //  .selectAsync((final String? v) => v?.firstName),
  // );

  // Only send event if 'Current Value' is not populated
  final String? currentValue = ref.watch(currentValueProvider);
  if (currentValue == null) {
    yield* Stream<String?>.value('Test Value');
  }

});

/// Text Widget
class TextWidget extends HookConsumerWidget {
  const TextWidget({ final Key? key, }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(final BuildContext context, final WidgetRef ref) {

    final TextEditingController controller = useTextEditingController();
    final FocusNode focusNode = useFocusNode();

    return Consumer(
        builder: (final BuildContext context, final WidgetRef ref, final Widget? child) {

          // Listen to Value Stream
          final String? value = ref.watch(valueStreamProvider).value;

          return TextFormField(
            key: UniqueKey(),
            focusNode: focusNode,
            controller: controller..text =  value ?? "",
            onChanged: (final String value) async {

              // Update 'Current Value' Provider
              ref.read(currentValueProvider.notifier).state = value;
            },
          );
        }
    );
  }
}
```

**pubspec.yaml**

```
name: test_text_field_stream
description: A new Flutter project.
publish_to: 'none'
version: 1.0.0+1
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.5 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_hooks: ^0.18.0
  hooks_riverpod: ^2.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

## Edit after

### To reply to Remi's kind feedback

Please see "The solution, with Remi's help (thanks!)" Answer to this post below.

### Further Queries

In regards to The solution, with Remi's help (thanks!)" Answer to this post below, we have the following further queries if we may:

1. If `skipLoadingOnReload` is not set to `true`, then the `ref.watch(valueStreamProvider).when` gets stuck `loading` - why is this? If we set `skipLoadingOnReload` = `true` this issue does not appear and the `data` returns as expected (i.e. builds / populates the `TextFormField` as expected)...
2. Within the `TextFormField` the `key: UniqueKey()` was actually supposed to be a `key: GlobalKey()` so that we can write integration tests which interact-with/test `TextFormField's` - guess it is recommended not to have a `key: GlobalKey()` within `TextFormField` and to instead add a parent `Container` with the `key: GlobalKey()` and access the child `TextFormField` from there in integration tests? Are there any good articles that explain 'when' and 'when not' to use `keys`, especially around `TextFormField's`, as it would be good to fully understand?
3. If we use a `controller` (`TextEditingController`) instead of the `initialValue` for the `TextFormField` (in our "To reply to Remi's kind feedback" example above), when the first character is entered into the `TextFormField` **(i)** the cursor jumps to the beginning of the `TextFormField`, and **(ii)** the first character entered never appears in the `TextFormField` but the 2nd character onwards does... Why is this, perhaps this is outside the scope of this particular post/question. Please see a full example below of this point 3 issue (pubspec.yaml is the same as the original example):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const ProviderScope(child: MyApp() ));
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData( primarySwatch: Colors.blue ),
      home: const Material(child: TextWidget()),
    );
  }
}

/// Riverpod Provider - current value
final currentValueProvider = StateProvider<String?>((final ref) => null);

/// Riverpod Provider - Value Stream
final valueStreamProvider = StreamProvider.autoDispose<String?>((final ref) async* {

  // DB Document StreamProvider watched here - *** not in use in this minimal
  // example *** but to illustrate why a StreamProvider is required
  // for valueStreamProvider
  // final String? firebaseDocumentStream = await ref.watch(firebaseDocumentStreamProvider
  //  .selectAsync((final String? v) => v?.firstName),
  // );

  // Only send event if 'Current Value' is not populated
  final String? currentValue = ref.watch(currentValueProvider);
  if (currentValue == null) {
    yield* Stream<String?>.value('Test Value');
  }

});

/// Text Widget
class TextWidget extends HookConsumerWidget {
  const TextWidget({ final Key? key, }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(final BuildContext context, final WidgetRef ref) {

    final controller = useTextEditingController();

    return ref.watch(valueStreamProvider).when(
      skipLoadingOnReload: true,
      data: (final String? value) => TextFormField(
        controller: controller..text = value ?? "",
        onChanged: (final String value) async {

          // Update 'Current Value' Provider
          ref.read(currentValueProvider.notifier).state = value;
        },
      ),
      error: (final Object err, final StackTrace stack)  =>
        throw Exception("Deal with error TODO: $err"),
      loading: () => const Text("Loading TODO"),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: HEllo! That `UniqueKey` is most likely the root of your problem. Why did you add this? It probably should be removed

Comment: Thank you sooo much Remi for the tip and for being so super fast! This certainly pointed us in the right direction and we have now solved the issue with your suggested change and a few others. 

It would be great if you could kindly put your nose over our final working version (we editing the post, please see the "To reply to Remi's kind feedback" part). We also have some follow-on queries if we may in the "Further Queries" above (again we edited the original post). Many many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### The solution, with Remi's help (thanks!)

Thank you to Remi for pointing us hard in the right direction - this is now working as expected with the following changes (full example below, pubspec.yaml is the same as the original example above):

1. Omit the `key: UniqueKey()` as kindly advised by Remi (thanks!!)
2. Implement `.when` when watching the `valueStreamProvider` `StreamProvider` (i.e. `ref.watch(valueStreamProvider).when`) and set `skipLoadingOnReload` = `true`
3. Replace the `controller` property with `initialValue` property within the `TextFormField`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const ProviderScope(child: MyApp() ));
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData( primarySwatch: Colors.blue ),
      home: const Material(child: TextWidget()),
    );
  }
}

/// Riverpod Provider - current value
final currentValueProvider = StateProvider<String?>((final ref) => null);

/// Riverpod Provider - Value Stream
final valueStreamProvider = StreamProvider.autoDispose<String?>((final ref) async* {

  // DB Document StreamProvider watched here - *** not in use in this minimal
  // example *** but to illustrate why a StreamProvider is required
  // for valueStreamProvider
  // final String? firebaseDocumentStream = await ref.watch(firebaseDocumentStreamProvider
  //  .selectAsync((final String? v) => v?.firstName),
  // );

  // Only send event if 'Current Value' is not populated
  final String? currentValue = ref.watch(currentValueProvider);
  if (currentValue == null) {
    yield* Stream<String?>.value('Test Value');
  }

});

/// Text Widget
class TextWidget extends HookConsumerWidget {
  const TextWidget({ final Key? key, }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(final BuildContext context, final WidgetRef ref) {

    return ref.watch(valueStreamProvider).when(
      skipLoadingOnReload: true,
      data: (final String? value) => TextFormField(
        initialValue: value,
        onChanged: (final String value) async {

          // Update 'Current Value' Provider
          ref.read(currentValueProvider.notifier).state = value;
        },
      ),
      error: (final Object err, final StackTrace stack)  =>
        throw Exception("Deal with error TODO: $err"),
      loading: () => const Text("Loading TODO"),
    );
  }
}
```